# How to remove this steam-launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, games, steam

it's useless to see that steam-launcher icon in unity dashboard ubuntu can't be clicked.
i already see in `/usr/share/applications` and `.local/share/applications` there is no such steam-launcher that UTF-8
please give me a clue how to remove this icon

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking around, there seems to have been a package named `steam-launcher` http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/0/371919771759899289/ but I can't find it in 15.10 and you don't say your Ubuntu version, so as a quick thing to try `sudo apt-get purge steam-launcher`, you may need to reinstall steam after `sudo apt-get install steam`

Comment: @MarkKirby solved it is package name steam-launcher in tmp files and after I delete it it's gone. Thank you. my ubuntu version is 14.04 btw.

Comment: Glad to help, please fell free to write and accept your own answer, to help anyone else with this issue.

Comment: @MarkKirby Alright, thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I get comment from @MarkKirby
I found that `steam-launcher` icon that was in unity the dashboard of ubuntu 14.04 is found in `/tmp` folder.

How to remove that file from search in unity dashboard?

After I found the file, I just simply moved it to trash, it's not an important file anyway.

After I remove that file it's gone from unity dashboard.
And steam still running as well.